# How do i use two dialog boxes in one application?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When i create two dialog boxes, only one shows up even if the condition for the other one is true..

Here's the code

```
    if (z<=18){   
       showDialog(1);
    } else {
       showDialog(3);
    }
...................................................................................................................................................................
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
      if (id== 1)
      {
            AlertDialog.Builder b=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            b.setTitle("1st dialog");
            b.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                  });
            AlertDialog d=b.create();
            d.show();
      } 
      else 
      {
          AlertDialog.Builder b2=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          b2.setTitle("2nd dialog ");         
          b2.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      }
                });

          AlertDialog dialoog=b2.create();
          dialoog.show();
      }
      return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
```

Comment: initialized?? float z= Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(tv.getText()));

Comment: And so are you checking what number that is giving you before the loop? `Log.d("TAG", "Z is:"+z);` p.s. if `z` is user input I would just make it an `int` `int z = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());`

Comment: So...just checked...both the dialog boxes are running, but even if the 2nd condition is true, the first dialog box starts,but if you click again with the same condition, the second dialog box appears.

Answer (score 0):

How can both conditions be true if you have them in if - else?

Answer (score 0):

How will both conditions ever be `true`? You are using an `if` `else` condition check which are exclusive to each other and only one of them will work at a time. Hence only one dialog is shown.

Comment: I thought he was saying, only one ( Dialog A ) ever appears even when his logic says Dialog B should show

Comment: Blindell-Yes, thats exactly what happens

Answer (score 0):

why don't you initialize both of your AlertDialogs, and depending of the situation you just show one:

defining the dialogs:

```
    //infodialog
    infodialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
    infodialog.setTitle("INFO");  
    infodialog.setMessage(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.info));  
    infodialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
        return;  }
    });
  //disclaimerdialog
    disclaimerdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();  
    disclaimerdialog.setTitle("Disclaimer");  
    disclaimerdialog.setMessage(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.disclaimer));  
    disclaimerdialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {  
        return;  }
    });
```

and picking one (i used a optionmenu and switch, you can use any if-function with your dialog.show ofcourse):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.info:
                    infodialog.show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.disclaimer:
                    disclaimerdialog.show();
                    return true;
```